# Using sed to replace text with 2 concatenated variables separated by "/"

Tags: bash, variables, sed, concatenation

I have a script that contains 2 variables. One of the variables is a directory path and the other is a user input variable. Once the user enters the variable, in this case a certificate name, I use sed to replace the text of xxxxx with both the script_path separated by a / and the the certfile variable.

Still new at programming but I've managed to get my script working aside from the issue below. I've tried escaping the variables the "/" and nothing seems to work.

I've also tried changing the delimiter that sed uses as well with no luck. I did search around quite a bit and didn't find anything specific with using a "/" and concatenating variables so apologies up front if this has already been solved.

```
#!/bin/bash
script_path=/opt/ceflog

read -p 'Enter the name of the certificate file: ' certfile
sed -e "s/pkcs12_file = xxxxxx/pkcs12_file = $script_path/$certfile/g" \$script_path/cef.conf
```

What is should look like is something like the below.

```
pkcs12_file = /opt/ceflog/192.168.1.1_1.pkcs12
```

As always thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem? You have a lot going on here, so I recommend making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do something like this

```
$ path='/opt/ceflog'; cert='192.168.1.1_1.pkcs12'; 
$ echo pkcs12_file = xxxxxx/pkcs12_file | 
  sed -E 's~(pkcs12_file =) (xxxxxx/pkcs12_file)~\1 '"${path}/${cert}"'~'


pkcs12_file = /opt/ceflog/192.168.1.1_1.pkcs12
```

use a different `sed` delimiter (here I picked `~`) than the default one (`/`), since you may have it in your data.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like there were 2 issues. I escaped the use of the variables on the end "\$script_path/cef.conf" and changing the dilemeter for sed I was able to get it to work.

```
sed -e "s|pkcs12_file = xxxxxx|pkcs12_file = $script_path/$certfile|g" $script_path/cef.conf
```

Thanks again all.